# how to bind window.location.hash change to router change in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I want user directly on one component by url.

so how to bind the window.location.hash change to router change in angular2?

Answer (score -1):

The angular docs help you https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location. angular $locationMethods
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: I'm sorry, Naresh Kumar,  i'm using angular2 and this's document is for angular1.x